# HP Envy 17 Switchable Graphics AMD/Intel

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, hp

So my wife finally asked me to install Ubuntu to her laptop after using it on mine and the machine I have setup for the kids.  Problem is I can't get the graphics drivers to install correctly.  She has the HP Envy 17 2090NR ([http://www.amazon.com/HP-ENVY-17-2090NR-Notebook-Silver/dp/B004SBBAV0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004SBBAV0)) with the ATI 6850/Intel 3000 combo(pretty sure the intel model is accurate anyway).  I have tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 and several different methods of installing the drivers.  After the driver install I attempt to run the sudo aticonfig --initial with varying degrees of success.  No matter what though I reboot to low graphics mode!  I have been in and read through the logs and it seems to be related to Ubuntu having no clue which graphics option to use.  I am not entirely sure how to pull the logs from said device but am willing to follow any advice that could be given.

Configuration File:---------------------------------------------------------------
Section "ServerLayout"
   Identifier "amd-layout"
   Screen 0 "amd-screen" 0 0
End Section

Section "Device"
   Identifier "intel"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
   BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier "amd-device"
   Driver "fglrx"
   BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "amd-monitor"
   Option "VendorName" "ATI Propietary Driver"
   Option "ModelName" Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
   Option "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier "amd-screen"
   Device "amd-device"
   Monitor "amd-monitor"
   DefaultDepth 24
   SubSection "Display"
      Viewport 0 0
      Depth 24
   EndSubSection
EndSection

---

### Xorg.log

[    17.751]
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[    17.751] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    17.751] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-70-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    17.751] Current Operating System: Linux NoKidsAllowed 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu
 SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64
[    17.751] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic   root=UUID=c89b31ad-f89b-4620-b33f-d149baeb51ea ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    17.752] Build Date: 10 December 2014  06:15:52PM
[    17.752] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.6 (For technical support please see  ubuntu/support)
[    17.752] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[    17.752]    Before reporting problems, check wiki.x.
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    17.752] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,

    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,

    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.

[    17.752] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Jan  7 17:48:10 2015

[    17.752] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"

[    17.752] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

[    17.753] (==) ServerLayout "amd-layout"

[    17.753] (**) |-->Screen "amd-screen" (0)
[    17.753] (**) |   |-->Monitor "amd-monitor"

[    17.753] (**) |   |-->Device "amd-device"
[    17.754] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    17.754] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    17.754] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    17.754] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    17.754]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    17.754] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    17.754]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    17.754] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    17.754]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    17.754] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    17.754]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    17.754] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    17.754]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    17.754] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    17.754] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,  /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    17.754] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    17.754] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f4bc76b0d40
[    17.754] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    17.754]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    17.754]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[    17.754]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[    17.754]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    17.755] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    17.757] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0116:103c:159b rev 9, Mem @ 0xc0000000/4194304,   0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00004000/64
[    17.758] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 1002:68a8:103c:159b rev 0, Mem @   0xa0000000/268435456,   0xc0700000/131072, I/O @ 0x00003000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension Present
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[    17.758] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    17.758] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    17.792] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/extensions  /libglx.so
[    17.793] (II) Module glx: vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc."
[    17.793]    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
[    17.793] Loading extension GLX
[    17.793] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    17.793] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/drivers  /fglrx_drv.so
[    17.839] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    17.839]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 13.35.5
[    17.839]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    17.840] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[    17.840] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[    17.840] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/linux  /libfglrxdrm.so
[    17.958] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    17.958]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 13.35.5
[    17.958] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:13.35.5
[    17.958] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: UNSUPPORTED-  13.35.1005
[    17.958] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: Mar 12 2014 10:32:23
[    17.958] (++) using VT number 7

[    17.959] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[    17.977] (II) Loading PCS database from /etc/ati/amdpcsdb /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
[    17.981] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
[    17.981] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
[    17.981] ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
[    17.981] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[    17.982] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[    18.375] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 9
[    18.375] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
[    18.378] (--) Chipset Supported AMD Graphics Processor (0x68A8) found
[    18.379] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@1:0:1)   found
[    18.379] (II) fglrx: intel VGA device detected, load intel driver.
[    18.379] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    18.379] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    18.398] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.398]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.99.910
[    18.398]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.398]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    18.398] (WW) PowerXpress feature is not supported on A+I Mux platform. Please   uninstall fglrx driver.
[    18.398] (EE) this is a Muxless PX A+I platform, we doesn't supported it
[    18.398] (EE) No devices detected.
[    18.398] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    18.398] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[    18.398] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    18.398] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    18.398] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    18.398] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    18.398] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    18.399] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    18.399] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.399]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.99.910
[    18.399]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.399]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    18.399] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[    18.399] (II) Unloading intel
[    18.399] (II) Failed to load module "intel" (already loaded, 32587)
[    18.399] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    18.400] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    18.400] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.400]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[    18.400]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.400]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    18.400] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    18.400] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    18.401] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.401]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[    18.401]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.401]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    18.401] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    18.401] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    18.401] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.401]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[    18.402]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    18.402]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    18.402] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:13.35.5
[    18.402] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: UNSUPPORTED-  13.35.1005
[    18.402] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: Mar 12 2014 10:32:23
[    18.402] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    18.402] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-5000
[    18.402] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100
[    18.402] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200
[    18.402] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    18.402] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    18.402] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    18.403] (++) using VT number 7

[    18.403] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setpgid failed: Operation not permitted
[    18.403] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setsid failed: Operation not permitted
[    18.403] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[    18.403] (II) Loading PCS database from /etc/ati/amdpcsdb /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
[    18.403] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    18.403] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    18.403] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    18.403] (EE) No devices detected.
[    18.403] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    18.403] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    18.403] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    18.403] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    18.403] (EE)

Comment: What made you install outer drivers when Ubuntu has built-in drivers?

Comment: There is considerable screen tearing at just the desktop level. I get a trail of mice icons similar to completing a game of windows solitaire.  Also I figured I would need the Catalyst Control Center in order to control the switchable graphics.